# Why specializing a generic function explicitly is not allowed?

Tags: swift

In Swift, one should use type of parameters or return value to implicitly specialize a generic function. The problem is, when I call function like this:

```
func serialize<T>(continuation: GenericWithLongName<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Void
```

I cannot just write

```
serialize<SomeType> {
    obj in 
    ...
}
```

It should be

```
serialize {
    (obj: GenericWithLongName<SomeType, NSError>) -> Void in
    ...
}
```

which looks painful.

It seems this "feature" exists for a long time. Is it a design decision? Is there any negative implication from allowing explicitly specialization?

And is there any way to make code above neat and clean without refactoring that generic class?

Comment: I'm with you! I wanted a function that returned an object of the generic type, similar to your case but de-serializing. Seems like the Swift 4 compiler should continue to try to infer the type, and at the same time check for an explicit type. If only one is possible then use that type, if both are possible throw a compile-time error if they mismatch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to "specialize" the function is by including the generic type as a function parameter:

```
func serialize<T>(
    t: T.Type, 
    continuation: GenericWithLongName<T, NSError> -> Void ) -> Void { }
```

Now you can "specialize" the function like this:

```
serialize(SomeType.self) { 
    obj in 
    ... 
}
```

I don't know the answer to why your requested feature is not available. I agree that the feature you recommend would be useful, but in the meantime this works just as well and is almost as concise.

Comment: Thanks for this! C# seems to work with let X: MyMethod<type>(), seems like the Swift designers may have taken elegance a step too far? Or perhaps this will be in Swift 5? :)